# Why is the superclasses field different when called from subclass?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

Why is field nodes returning different size when called from subclass

shouldn't subclasses have access to their super classes fields?

Here is reproducible example:

**Manager.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Manager {
    protected HashMap<Integer,Node> nodes = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<Integer, Node> getNodes() { return nodes; }

    public void addNode(Node node){
        nodes.put(nodes.size(),node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.addNode(new Node());
        System.out.println("(from Manager) manager.nodes.size() = " + manager.nodes.size());
        manager.getNodes().get(0).printNodesSize();
    }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node extends Manager {
    public void printNodesSize() {
        System.out.println("(from Node) manager.nodes.size() = " + super.nodes.size());
    }
}
```

System.out:

```
(from Manager) manager.nodes.size() = 1
(from instanced Node) manager.nodes.size() = 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I suggest you step through this with your debugger, so you can examine all your objects after each line of code.  I suspect that the `Map` isn't storing what you think it is.

Comment: Yeah I think I need to go back and review how extending classes works. I'm gonna get rid of it for now and just call the info statically. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having has nothing to see with inheritance. The call:

```
manager.getNodes()
```

will return a `Map<Integer, Node>` (check your own method definition in the class `Manager`) that contains only one element with index `1` (because it's you defining the key as `nodes.size()+1`).

Hence when you call `manager.getNodes().get(0)`, you get a `null` element (the map doesn't contain any element with key `0`).

If you replace `.get(0)` by `.get(1)`, it will work.

Side note: your design is not very clean. The class `Manager` (parent) contains a map of `Node`s which is its own child. The child (`Node`) is supposed to know its parent (`Manager`), but not vice versa.

**Edit**

The print of `super.nodes.size()` is 0 because you're not pointing to the instance of `Manager` that you think you're pointing to.

When you do `new Node()` (the node that you add to your `manager`), you're creating a `new Manager()` which has an empty map by default.

So when you call `super.nodes.size()`, your `super` is not `manager` as you think, but the other instance of `Manager` that you created when doing `new Node()`, to which you never added anything.

Again, I suggest you check my side-note above and re-consider your design.

Comment: Thank you I will update my question. This was an error while making MRE. The size of nodes according to a node instance is still 0.

Comment: @Fmxerz please check my edit

Comment: Thank you, it took me a minute but I think I understand what your saying. When you instance a subclass it implicitly instances a superclass? The reason I have it structured this way is because nodes need access to sibling info. I was previously accessing nodes as a static field in Manager. I noticed I could maybe use super to get that info instead but it is turning in to a headache and lots of changes in my full code.

Comment: @Fmxerz yes, that's the all principle of inheritance. A Dog cannot exist on its own without having an Animal behind it. If you have D extends C extends B extends A, when you do a new D() you will create as well a new C(), that creates a new B(), that creates a new A(), that creates a new Object() because everything in Java extends Object (except for primitives)

Comment: @Fmxerz as for the design, you may have your reasons of course. But what I mean is that it's very weird, from a theoretical point of view, to have the parent class being aware of its child. I think the whole design should be re-visited, but of course not under a comment (maybe in a new question for Code Review)